# average and if conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

=IFERROR(IF(AR3="Station"),AVERAGE(Data!C26:C37)/32,"")

I am trying to get the average of the cell range c26:c37 divided by 32 from  the sheet data but only if the  cell AR3 on my current sheet is equal to the string "station". I've tried everything I know and cant get it to work. I get an error saying not trying to type a formula.

Comment: Try `=IFERROR(IF(AR3="Station",AVERAGE(Data!C26:C37)/32,""),"")`

Comment: sorry for got to mention if no values are in the range (c26:c37)then return empty cell

Comment: So like `=IF(AR3="Station",IFERROR(AVERAGE(Data!C26:C37)/32,""),"")`?

Comment: @findwindow Yea if that returns an empty cell if the range is empty then yea.